# How to get direct URL to multipart file uploaded via Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I wish to post file to multipart form and upload it to Amazon S3 Bucket and return to user link to the file.

```js
const express = require('express'),
    aws = require('aws-sdk'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: 'secret',
    accessKeyId: 'secret',
    region: 'us-east-2'
});

const app = express(),
    s3 = new aws.S3();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'some-name',
        key: (req, file, cb) => {
            console.log(file);
            cb(null, file.originalname); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
        }
    })
});

app.post('/upload', upload.array('file',1), (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("How to return File URL?");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

How can I have the direct URL to the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

([Multer NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)) has already written there in documentation:

#### .single(fieldname)     => *(req.file)*

Accept a single file with the name fieldname. The single file will be stored in **req.file**.

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Uploaded!');
    res.send(req.file);
});
```

#### .array(fieldname[, maxCount])     => *(req.files)*

Accept an array of files, all with the name fieldname. Optionally error out if more than maxCount files are uploaded. The array of files will be stored in **req.files**.

```
app.post('/upload', upload.array('file', 1), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Uploaded!');
    res.send(req.files);
});
```

#### .fields(fields)     => *(req.files)*

Accept a mix of files, specified by fields. An object with arrays of files will be stored in **req.files**

```
app.post('/upload', upload.fields([
  { name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 },
  { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }
]), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Uploaded!');
    res.send(req.files);
});
```

#### .any()     => *(req.files)*

Accepts all files that comes over the wire. An array of files will be stored in **req.files**.

#### .none()

Accept only text fields. If any file upload is made, error with code "LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE" will be issued.

Answer (score 2):

U could get it from the location property of the file.

```
res.send(req.file.location);
```

Comment: Not getting full url this way, it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

> req.file.location

in the Success Response