# How to get s3 bucket uploaded object url using multer?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This code is upload objects on s3 successfully but I was not able to figure out how to get uploaded object url return.

**Code snnipet**

```
let s3 = new aws.S3({
        accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        region: 'XXXXXXXX'
    });
    let upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            acl: 'public-read',
            bucket: 'XXXXXXXXXXx',
            metadata: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {                    
                cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
            },
            key: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
                cb(null, Date.now().toString() + '-' + file.originalname)
            }
        })
    });

    routes.post(`api/upload-image`, upload.single('photo'), async (req: any, res: Response) => {
        
        res.send('Image uploaded successfully');
    });
```

Is there any way or callback for getting the url?

Comment: what are you getting when you do this `console.log(req.file)` ?

Comment: I'm getting Undefined

Comment: just tested code is working perfectly, you can check again your credentials or configurations of s3, confirm again image is uploading in s3 and verify name of the image. you can get file details using `req.file` this is the final.

Comment: It's working absolutely as expected. Thanks for help. You can also give answer to this question in details if you want for other developers.

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: Not sure! I think I was looking into res object since then. :-(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get direct URL to multipart file uploaded via Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054367/how-to-get-direct-url-to-multipart-file-uploaded-via-node-js)

Comment: Anyway, `req.file.location` may give you the url of the uploaded stuff.

Answer (score -1):

- `multer` middleware puts all the information regarding uploaded in the `req.file`.
- The uploaded file url can be accessed as `req.file.location`

```
let s3 = new aws.S3({
        accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        region: 'XXXXXXXX'
    });
    let upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            acl: 'public-read',
            bucket: 'XXXXXXXXXXx',
            metadata: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {                    
                cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
            },
            key: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
                cb(null, Date.now().toString() + '-' + file.originalname)
            }
        })
    });

    routes.post(`api/upload-image`, upload.single('photo'), async (req: any, res: Response) => {
        
       return res.json({message:'Image uploaded successfully',uploadLocation:req.file.location});
    });
```

Comment: Well, at least give some comments or description about the answer. Just posting a bunch of code doesn't help that much.