# How to solve "can not read property path of undefined" in node.js(Multer)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I want to upload an image to mongodb using multer. Here is my code :

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
});
```

Inside mongoClient:

```
client.connect((err) => {
const adminTasks = client
    .db(`${process.env.DB_NAME}`)
    .collection("adminTasks");

app.post("/uploadImage", upload.single("myImage"), (req, res) => {
    const img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    const encode_image = img.toString(base64);

    // defining json obj for image
    const final_image = {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
      path: req.file.path,
      image: new Buffer(encode_image, "base64"),
    };

    // inserting image to db
    userTasks.insertOne(final_image, (err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log("saved to db");
      res.contentType(final_image.contentType);
      res.send(final_image.image);
    });
  });
});
```

and the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

I have read many problems regarding that the problem occurs due to enctype="multipart/form-data". But I have used this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:5000/uploadImage" method="POST">
          <input type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myImage" />
          <input type="submit" value="upload Image" />
        </form>
```

How to fix this problem????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get direct URL to multipart file uploaded via Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054367/how-to-get-direct-url-to-multipart-file-uploaded-via-node-js)

Comment: no , I can not understand the suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

With `upload.single()`, the filename is in `req.file`.  That's a string that represents the filename.  There is no property `req.file.path`.  So, you should be using `req.file` to get the filename.

Comment: using req.file, the new error is----> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined

Comment: @Fuad9 - What does `console.log(typeof req.file)` show?

Comment: the error is showing for --> const img = fs.readFileSync(req.file); 

at Object.openSync (fs.js:450:10)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:360:35)
    

and the typeof req.file is showing undefined

Comment: @Fuad9 - OK, if `typeof req.file` shows `undefined, then you have an upstream problem with multer.  Perhaps your `const storage = ...` part is wrong.  I don't know multer enough to help you there.

Answer (score 0):

file.fieldname may be undefined. That is why the complete path becomes undefined.

Instead, try looking at req.file for the name. Here is what worked for me:

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
}
```

The documentation incorrectly states in a general manner that the storage configuration should contain

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname)
}
```